# Variable with char[] name

Tags: c

How can I make variable in C with name specified in char table?

something like:

```
char name[];
gets(name[]);
int name[] = 0;
```

I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: So a dynamically named variable?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by `name specified in char table`

Comment: @user3217192 you need to use pointers bro.

Comment: can any1 give me some example, pls :3

Comment: http://denniskubes.com/2012/08/16/the-5-minute-guide-to-c-pointers/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C, unlike scripting languages ala Python, or Ruby which you may be used to, is compiled not interpreted. At runtime, C does not have a look up table of variable names like the aforementioned scripting languages, this information is thrown away at compile time and thus, any name that is calculated at run-time cannot be turned into an address.

Ultimately, as you describe it this is impossible in compiled languages. However, we do have an alternative, found in Collections such as vectors and HashMaps which store naming information at run-time, allowing us to access it. Again, unfortunately, C does not have any native implementations of these, but there are some around.

Comment: ohhhhhh i see what he means by char table now!

Comment: If i understand what you were meaning by your answer, I disagree.  C does Quir, the preprocessor phase which has it's symbol and lookup table.

Comment: @Ion The preprocessor phase is one of the initial stages of compile-time. All that information is lost after the fact.

Comment: Yes, but if he's looking to allocate it at compilation, that will indeed insert say a command line arg, whether it's a name, function text, and so forth into the program during compilation.

Comment: There are no advantages to that over just hardcoding a name though.

Comment: Hardcoding means is static, using preprocessor commands to parse command line input makes it dynamic.  So he could put into that char table whatever he pleases, during each compile.

Comment: @Ion I'm well aware, but using pre-processor commands does not make it "dynamic", You just have to use the pre-processor macro wherever you would use the variable name, in which case you could just have given it a variable name and called it a day.

Comment: I do not think it is a compiled vs. interpretered difference. Python also a compiled programming language, but instead of compiled to an assembly language, it compiled to bytecode of Python interpreter. So it is actually a difference between static and dynamic programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. At least not with the vanilla C language features. But remember, C has [pointers](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm) which sometimes can do something similar.

If pointers aren't what you need, you will have to implement a [hash map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). Higher level programming languages have them built in, but C doesn't.

You could find a library, but if you are doing this for learning, I would recomend implimenting it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want.  C does have a lookup table in the form of the preprocessor table where you define keywords and the text that goes with them, which are added at compilation time.  So you could pass a name or whatever you want as an arg to the program during compilation and if you code it right, it will affix that name during the preprocessor portion of the compilation phase to your variable.  Preprocesor phase is what looks at your #include at the top, as well as things such as #ifndef...#def, #if...#endif and so forth, [C preprocessor example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)

Comment: I just found this [C/C++ trick: static lookup table generation](http://lolengine.net/blog/2011/12/20/cpp-lookup-table-generation)

Comment: @James that's a good link to show the behavior of the preprocessor.